# Arrays in PHP. Taking off a variable from array

Tags: php, arrays

Imagine this code:

```
$array1 = "20";
$array2 = "40";
$array3 = "";
$arraydate = array($array1,$array2,$array3); //In this case would be array("20","40","0")
```

So what I want is that when there is a variable that is null, 0 or empty, then do not make part of the array. The solution to this is to pass from:

```
array("20","40","0")
```

to:

```
array("20","40")
```

Is there anyway to do this? Sorry for my bad english. Thank you :D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$arraydate = array_filter($arraydate);`

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), if no callback is given, it will remove all items that equal to false.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually looked in the PHP Manual? They provide a one line solution with array_filter...

```
$newAray = array_filter($arraydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Imagination this would never result to  array("20","40","0"), it would be instead
   array ( "20", "40", "")

And even of you are getting that then use array_filter function to filter value

Comment: That's the thing, that's what I would like to be possible